# Django python path with Apache and mod_python

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to set up Review Board, which uses Django, on WinXP with Apache 2.2 and mod-python.

I have a default Python install, but I want to use a different instance. The default is c:/python25, but I want d:/xxx/python25. mod-python has a config option to change the path, but I don't want to have to recompile mod_python (as the code is in VCS and could be put anywhere). How can I fix this?

Currently I'm trying to change the environment path using SetEnv in the Apache conf file, e.g.

```
SetEnv PATH "d:/xxx/python25;PATH"
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
```

I.e. setting the environment variable before mod-python is loaded as this is where it finds the Python interpretter.

This doesn't seem to work. Is the syntax wrong? Is there another solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on windows, it's possible it's referencing the registry for the path.  Try looking in the registry under:

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.5`

In particular, the subkeys, `InstallPath`, `Modules`, and `PythonPath`.

Comment: I guess this is all I can do bar recompile mod_python, which I want to avoid. I think Python and the Review Board dependencies will have to be installed rather than got from VCS. Not a big problem since only need one instance of RB really.